# How to map a Firestore DocumentID to a RealmObject attribute?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, realm

I'm trying to provide some data in the cloud with Firestore that can be downloaded and stored in a Realm database on an iOS device.
The structure of my object that I want to store is:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

@objcMembers class Flashcard: Object, Codable{

@objc dynamic var id: String? = NSUUID().uuidString 
@objc dynamic var character: String?
@objc dynamic var title: String?
@objc dynamic var translation: String?
@objc dynamic var created: Date = Date()
let deck = LinkingObjects<FlashcardDeck>(fromType: FlashcardDeck.self, property: "cards")

override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case character
    case translation
    case created
    case title
}
```

If I try to map the documentID to my `id` attribute with

```
@DocumentID @objc dynamic var id: String? = NSUUID().uuidString
```

If get the following error:

```
'Primary key property 'id' does not exist on object 'Flashcard'
```

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: To make it more understandable here is a screenshot of my Firestore database:

[image]

The collection "PredifinedDecks" will store many decks. For example the `id = DF59B1B3-BD22-47CE-81A6-04E7A274B98F` represents one deck. Each deck will store an array/List with cards in it.

Comment: The id was omitted from the coding keys enum. Also, `@DocumentID` is not optional - generally speaking, if you're importing JSON into a codable object, the documentId would be populated like this: `@DocumentID var docId: String!`. That being said, Firebase snapshot documents can be accessed by their field values, why jump through codable hoops when you can just access the fields directly? `self.a = doc.get("a") as? String ?? "default value"`

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I've forgotten the id in the coding keys. But it was just a typo and it was already in my code. I feel like your advice accessing the document by their field values is helpful when I have only one document, but in my case I have two other different classes/object types I want to store in firestore. Can you maybe give me a more detailed example?

Comment: The number of documents won't make a difference to your object structure - generally speaking, each document in the collection maps to one document in your code. Are you saying you're storing dissimilar data as separate documents in the *same collection*?

Comment: No, my structure looks like:
DECK 1: List(card1, card2,...) / DECK2: List(card3, card4,...) where Deck and Card are different types of objects.

Comment: That's not very clear as we don't know how that lays out in your structure. Perhaps you can include a screen shot of your firebase structure in the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Jay I've edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the question but let me address this at a high level.

It appears there is a PredefinedDecks (a collection) that contains documents. Each document has a field (an array) of cards and some other field data. If the goal is to read in all of the documents (the decks) and their child data and store them as Realm objects, here's one solution. Start with a Realm object to hold the data from Firestore

```
class DeckClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var deck_id = ""
    @objc dynamic var created = ""
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    let cardList = List<CardClass>()

    convenience init(withDoc: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.deck_id = withDoc.documentID
        self.title = withDoc.get("title") as? String ?? "no title"
        self.created = withDoc.get("created") as? String ?? "no date"
        let cardArray = withDoc.get("cards") as? [String]
        for card in cardArray {
            let card = CardClass(withCard: card) {
                self.cardList.append(card)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you simply pass the documentSnapshot from Firestore for each document and the class will populate its properties accordingly.

and the code to read Firestore

```
func readDecks() {
    let decksCollection = self.db.collection("PredefinedDecks")
    decksCollection.getDocuments(completion: { documentSnapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        for doc in documentSnapshot!.documents {
            let deck = DeckClass(withDoc: doc)
            self.decksList.append(deck) //a Realm List class object? Something else?
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be the solution for my use case. What's the most efficient way to store a RealmObject in the Firestore database?

Comment: @kirkyoyx That's going to be really hard to say without more context. In other words, *technically* you could encode a realm object and store that object in Firestore (as a string for example). But I don't think that's what you want. Also, Realm has made huge leaps forward this last year in providing a product that in some ways can do what Firestore does - thereby potentially eliminating Firestore completely, simplifying the project. So we would need to understand the purpose of doing that, what data you want to get to, why Firestore etc. e.g. Probably best suited for a separate question.